# bootstrap grids act differently in different chrome versions

Tags: google-chrome, grid, version

bootstrap grids act differently in different chrome versions. In older versions it looks O.k but in latest version it looks messy. What should I do?  Please help.

Comment: can you put the code here to see how it looks http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Foruz Mehdiani users will be able to help you if you ask a more specific question